# How to Assign String that is split to new Variables?

Tags: c, string, token

Maybe the title can be confusing, but I mean that I have a code as below:

```
char str[25]="hello my name is  ";
const char ayir[]=" ";
char *token;

token=strtok(str,ayir);
while( token !=NULL ) {
    printf( "%s\n", token );
    token = strtok(NULL, ayir);
}
```

and I just want to assign variable (token) that has 4 strings which are "hello", "my", "name", "is" to new String array like "char *string[4]".
However,I haven't achieved so far.

Comment: First step would be to actually have such a string array. Also, please make a [mcve] of what you have but does not yet behave as desired.

Comment: @Yunnosch `char *string[4]` will work, provided that the content of `char str[25]` does not change - but in many questions of this nature, it does (such as reading lines of text from a file) in which case the substrings must be copied.

Comment: I have an array like "char *string[4]" ,and should I use this array in the while block like this : string[0]=token ?

Comment: @WeatherVane Of course it will work, but only if it is actually used in the code. At least for definition, maybe even assignment. I would just like to see more of OPs experiments, to get rid of the nagging impression that this is a "write code for me" question. I am willing to assume that it is not, but the impression is so overwhelming.

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm just  trying to solve the problem in stm32 microcontroller.I want to take data from the mobil phone via the bluetooth ,and separate the data into parts,and this problem that I asked is not something like "please can you do that for me".I just want you all to show me a way ..

Comment: Scan `str` for a letter and assign the address to `string[0]`.  Scan `str` for space character and set to `NUL`.  Continue.

Comment: @WeatherVane   I tried this in the while block :
 for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
       string[i]=token;
       
   }
and outside of while block :
printf("%s\n",string[0]);
     printf("%s\n",string[1]);
     printf("%s\n",string[2]);
     printf("%s\n",string[3]); . but the output is like that :
is
is
is
İs

Comment: I see.  You need `token` to be an array of `char *`: `token[i++] = strtok(..., ayir);`

Comment: @FiddlingBits yes it terminates

Comment: Your output is `is` because you're overwriting `token`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits now I'll try all what you said ,thank you for your answers and helps :=) and I'll report to you

Comment: @FiddlingBits should I take both of token=strtok(str,ayir); and token =strtok(NULL, ayir); into for loops?

Comment: `token[i]=strtok(str,ayir);` should be outside the loop and `token[i] =strtok(NULL, ayir);` should be inside the loop.  Make sure you increment `i` for each call to `strtok`.

Comment: "*new String array like `char *string[4]`*" here `string` is *not* an array of strings but an array of pointer to `char`, to a c-strings 1st element, a `char`, either itself having a value of `'\0'` or being followed by one or more `char` with the last one having a value of `'\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `strtok` does not create new strings. Especially when you would re-use the string being tokenized, you must copy the tokens to new memory.

If your input buffer is not re-used, then this is the simple version:

```
#define MAX_TOKENS 4
char str[25]="hello my name is  ";
const char ayir[]=" ";
char *token, *tokens[MAX_TOKENS];
int i= 0;

token=strtok(str,ayir);
while (token !=NULL && i<MAX_TOKENS) {
    tokens[i]= token;
    printf( "%s\n", tokens[i] );
    i++;
    token = strtok(NULL, ayir);
}
```

If your input buffer is re-used, then you must also allocate new memory:

```
#define MAX_TOKENS 4
char str[25]="hello my name is  ";
const char ayir[]=" ";
char *token, *tokens[MAX_TOKENS];
int i= 0;

token=strtok(str,ayir);
while (token !=NULL && i<MAX_TOKENS) {
    tokens[i]= malloc(strlen(token)+1);
    strcpy(tokens[i], token);
    printf( "%s\n", tokens[i] );
    i++;
    token = strtok(NULL, ayir);
}
```

Comment: `malloc` is unnecessay because `str` is modified to `NUL` terminate at `" "`, right?

Comment: @FiddlingBits, I think you are right (I don't have `strtok` in my libs). I thought for a moment it put the terminator back in the next call. The documentation doesnt say so, so it doesn't.